# In welcher deutschen Mundart wurde das DWB (Deutsches Wörterbuch) verfasst?

Tags: dialect

Ich bin kein Muttersprachler und finde alle Informationen im DWB ziemlich schwierig zu verstehen.

In welcher Mundart wurde das Wörterbuch verfasst, und war es das alltägliche bzw. gewöhnliche Deutsch zu der Zeit als es verfasst wurde?

Comment: Please [be nice](https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct) to each other and try not to use comments for meta discussions. All this should take place on [meta] or in [chat]. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Kurzfassung

- Kein Dialekt (keine Mundart)
- kein Alltagsdeutsch (keine Umgangssprache)
- ca. 150 Jahre altes Standarddeutsch (überregional normierte Dachsprache)

---

### im Detail

Das [deutsche Wörterbuch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_W%C3%B6rterbuch) der Gebrüder Grimm (das auch *»der Grimm«* genannt wird) wurde von den beiden Sprachwissenschaftlern und Volkskundlern [Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%BCder_Grimm) verfasst.

- Jacob Grimm: 1785 – 1863
- Wilhelm Grimm: 1786 – 1859

Die beiden begannen im Jahr 1838 mit ihrer Arbeit. Im Jahr 1854, also vor 166 Jahren, erschien der erste Band. Damit erschien die erste Ausgabe 22 Jahre **vor** der allerersten offiziellen Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Rechtschreibung, die unter dem Begriff *[Erste Orthographische Konferenz von 1876](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1876)* in die Geschichte einging.

Die Gebrüder Grimm leisteten damit Pionierarbeit bei der Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Sprache, und sie unterschätzten den Aufwand ihres Projektes beträchtlich:

Jakob Grimm gelang es gerade mal, die Beiträge jener Wörter fertigzustellen, die mit den Buchstaben A, B, C und E begannen. Er starb im Jahr 1863, nach 25 Jahren Arbeit an dem Werk. Sein Bruder Wilhelm, der den Buchstaben D fertig bearbeitet hatte, starb schon 4 Jahre früher. Zu dieser Zeit arbeiteten rund 80 Mitarbeiter daran, im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum Belege für das Wörterbuch zu sammeln.

Der letzte Band erschien 1961, also 123 Jahre nach Beginn des Projekts, und rund 100 Jahre nach dem Tod der Gründer des Wörterbuches (und somit knapp 60 Jahre vor dem heutigen Tag).

Die Sprache, der dieses Wörterbuch verfasst wurde, ist kein Dialekt, und somit auch keine Mundart (Mundart = Verwendung von Dialekten in Literatur und Musik), sondern [Standard-Deutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standarddeutsch). Das ist jene normierte Dachsprache, in der Texte verfasst werden, die überregional von jedem deutschen Muttersprachler verstanden werden sollen.

Allerdings ist das Deutsch im *Grimm* ein mittlerweile veraltetes Deutsch (es ist rund 150 Jahre alt), und zum anderen entschieden sich die beiden Brüder, ihr Werk in konsequenter Kleinschreibung zu verfassen. Großgeschrieben wurden nur Absatzanfänge und Eigennamen. Das war möglich, weil es zum Zeitpunkt der Erstveröffentlichung noch keine allgemein gültigen Rechtschreibregeln gab. Diese wurden erstmals erst im Jahr 1876 in der schon erwähnten Ersten Orthographischen Konferenz festgelegt.